# Show file size by type in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to find out the total size of all files within a directory that have a particular extension.

I do some offsite backup via rsync but due to limited bandwidth and disk space at the other end I can't do everything, so I'd like to find out, for example, how much disk space MP3 files take up so I can decide whether to remove the mp3 extension from the current list of rsync excluded patterns.

It's not as simple as doing a 'du -sh' on the My Music directory in there as there's some other file types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **can** use du:

```
find Music/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec du -shc {} + | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

output example:

```
980M
```

Comment: I tried this on 100K+ text files and got 26M when I expected around 4G, but this answer worked better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/599079/172602

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following

```
find Music/ -name '*.mp3' -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{ SUM += $5} END { print SUM/1024/1024 }'
```

And got the correct answer in Megabytes (1024 x 1024)

Comment: Right on, works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
find Music/ -iname "*.mp3" -type f -exec stat -c "%s" {} \; | awk '{SUM+=$0} END {print SUM/1024/1024}'
```

Got the correct answer as well, exactly the same as pavium's solution, could be a bit more reliable though.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is the best way I have seen which seems to execute orders of magnitude faster than ones containing awk:

`find "My Music/" -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1`

output:

`1.3G Total`